# momentum theorem more general than Newton's 2nd law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, soft-question, education

Now that momentum theorem is more general than Newton's 2nd law, as the former incorporates the variable mass scenario, while the latter doesn't, why is Newton's 2nd law put at a higher status? By momentum theorem I mean F=p'.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: What is "momentum theorem" ? Perhaps you mean momentum conservation. This is based in field theory on Noether's theorem. It is indeed more general for example because it takes into account the massless case.

Comment: By momentum theorem I mean F=p'

Comment: Careful: the statement put forward by Newton and now named after him was that force is equal to rate of change of momentum, NOT force is equal to mass times acceleration. Thus the answer provided here by Krishna is correct.

Comment: @AndrewSteane The question does not seem to be about history of the law though, but rather about current status of it.

Comment: @Umaxo the current status is that Newton's 2nd law is $f=dp/dt$. (And sometimes this is equal to $ma$).

Comment: @AndrewSteane what you said 'the statement put forward by Newton and now named after him was that force is equal to rate of change of momentum, NOT force is equal to mass times acceleration.'. I don't think it's the case

Comment: @feynman Your 'I don't think' here suggests merely that you have been miss-taught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reason might be that $F=ma$ is more simple and intuitive than $F=\dot{p}.$

The second and deeper reason might be that at fundamental level, the law applies only to point masses. The law tells you the acceleration of the object in question, which is second time derivative of its position. Finite object however has no such position. Even the simplest case of rigid body needs at least 6 coordinates to make sure you know how the object is placed in 3D space.

So you either need to approximate the object by point mass (by putting all the mass into its center of mass) or as a collection of point masses. Only then can the law be used.

Now in mechanics there is conservation of mass and in the domain of Newtonian physics there is no process that can change mass of the fundamental point masses which are used to build up the whole object.

Take for example spaceship with propulsion engine. The force law is applicable only for center of mass, but the center is not moving. To describe movement of spaceship itself, you need to make the spaceship into composition of bare spaceship and fuel particles. Then the position of each constituent is again well defined, but then neither of the constituents is changing its mass.

The fact, that you can describe spaceship by formula $F=\dot{p}$ is consequence of the third law of motion, it is not fundamental law.

Answer (score 1):

According to Newton's Second law, "the rate of change of momentum is directly proportional to applied force and is in the direction of force"

$F= \frac{dp}{dt}$ is precisely Newton's second law. Why would (or how would) you put a thing over itself?

Comment: when mass changes, they are different

Comment: @feynman, F=ma is a special case of Newton's second law as opposed to the original form of Newton's second law.